# Creating for loop in 5x5 table

Tags: javascript

I am a newb and I am trying to make my for loop output into a html 5x5 data table.  So far I have the following code...

```
  <table  border=" 1 solid black">
    <script>
    for (var i=1; i<=25;i++)
    {
      document.write("<tr><td>" + i +"</td></tr>");
    }
    </script>
  </table>
```

it is obviously flawed but I am having trouble working out on my own.  Any help would be awesome!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (var j=1; j<=5; j++) {
        document.write("<td>" + i + " " + j + "</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
```

I would propose you to use JQuery or JSTL (if it's Java application).

**JQuery**
It should be something like (just put it into a loop):

```
$("#tableId tbody").append("<tr><td>content</td></tr>");
```

**JSTL**
Use `<c:forEach>` tag to generate a table.

**JavaScript**
You could use `insertRow` method, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

Comment: This works but I think it's ugly. Instead of all these document.write statements, you should be building a string in the loop and then once you're done looping you should have only one document.write statement.

Comment: I would have used `x` and `y` as variables - but that is me?!

Comment: @frenchie I agree, I never generate this way myself, just to make it work using author's technique. It's better to use JSTL or JQuery.

Comment: @EdHeal `i` and `j` are kind of a standard :) The only difference is that I'd start from `0` ;)

Comment: @Alex: agreed, using $(selector).html(SomeHTML); is much better but you answered the original question. May be you can also show the OP the better approach.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov - Did not realise it was a "standard". Just would use mathematical standard for a grid!

Comment: @EdHeal I see what you're saying, I didn't mean it's standard per-se, emmm - It's more of a habit that I have - `int i = 0` -> then `int j = 0` ... then comes `int k = ...` arghh :) forget it, dude :P

Comment: So when I changed the for loop it outputted 1-5 in every single row and cell and so it all doubled up.  How would I make it so 1-5 was on row 1, 6-10 was on the second and so on?

Comment: @user2684772 document.write("<td>" + (5*(i-1)+j) + "</td>");

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov - I try to avoid getting into the habit - you end up in a nunnery ;->

Comment: @EdHeal AHAHAHAH :)))) Cheers